# How to deploy an Express Server and React App separately, connected by WebSocket/WebSocketServer

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, heroku, websocket

I'm building a chess app to play vs other people online.

I have an Express Server in which I've layed out the server as follows:

```
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3001
const INDEX = '/index.html';

const server = express()
  .use((req, res) => res.sendFile(INDEX, { root: __dirname }))
  .listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Listening on ${PORT}`))

const { Server } = require('ws')
const wss = new Server({ server })
```

This is deployed to Heroku

I also have a React App deployed to Netlify which contains:

```
export default function Board() {
    const connection = new WebSocket("ws://heroku-domain.com")

    useEffect(() => {
        connection.onopen = () => {
            console.log('connection established')
        }

        connection.onmessage = (message) => {
            // does stuff
        }
     }, [])

    return (
        {content}
    )
}
```

I've tested the WebSocket connection on localhost with the React App running on 3000, the server running on 3001 and replacing the connection in the React App with

```
const connection = new WebSocket(document.location.origin.replace(/^http/, 'ws').replace('3000', '3001'))
```

and it worked great.

What I'm having trouble with is once I've deployed them, being able to point the client to the correct source on the server. If I need to include `` new WebSocket(`ws://heroku-domain.com:${PORT}`) `` and if so, how I could get the correct port number given it's dynamically provided by Heroku.

My thought was to create an api route on the server to retrieve the correct port number, and then implant that in the WebSocket arg.

Is there any cleaner way of doing it than this?

Comment: websockets run on the standard http and https ports 80 and 443. You can leave that off in most cases.

Comment: So in that case ```const connection = new WebSocket("ws://heroku-domain.com")``` should just work? 

As it is I'm not able to get a connection, I don't get any error messages, however the connection.onopen code never runs.

Comment: Nevermind, it's working for me now, thanks for the help. :)